# How safe are my passwords at after-sales service?

Tags: security, password, data-recovery

My phone is currently inoperative. Samsung asked me to drop it at an approved repair center, which will handle shipment and reception to/from Samsung.

Being unable to boot my phone, it was impossible for me to remove personal files from it.

I am aware all my files will be accessible to anyone handling my phone, once repaired. But what about my passwords ? I know it's possible to get saved WiFi passwords with root access. Is it possible too for passwords from applications ? (Gmail, Dropbox, Website passwords from Chrome, ...)

**Bottom line:** How safe are my data/passwords on an **un**encrypted device ?

Comment: Possibly relevant to you: [How is the Gmail password stored in Android - and where?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29192)

Comment: Do you store website passwords in Chrome? Or, you're talking about logged in session of websites?

Comment: I do talk about stored website passwords. (I guess logged in session will be expired by the time Samsung will repair my device, isn't it?)

Comment: Some websites and services, such as Gmail, have an option to "logout from all other devices" which enables you to end the session stored in your mobile and any other devices you logged in previously. Just login to the service from any pc/device and find that option (if available). I'm not sure if it works with Google account integration into Android devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### General information

As *The Andro Nerd* pointed out in [his answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/34219/16575), *most* apps store passwords (and other sensitive information) encrypted. Some even don't store them at all (they use a kind of "tokens", as is available with most Google apps -- or they don't store anything like that).

Unfortunately, only *most* apps seem to care this way. Some store everything plain text (the stock email app on some HTC devices is known for that, for example: Storing passwords and even directory information plain text for Exchange services. Sources for this allegation can be found in the book mentioned below).

### Which apps are safe?

It's hard to really *know* which apps are save, though some services help you figure it out -- see e.g. ViaForensic's [AppWatchdog](https://viaforensics.com/appwatchdog/), where they thoroughly investigate apps for things like that (but with limited ressources are *far* from covering everything). Some security blogs inform about found issues as well -- and if some well-known app is affected by such a security hole (as e.g. mentioned email app, or [Skype](http://www.pcworld.com/article/225382/Skype_for_Android_Security_Flaw_Wha__You_Need_to_Know.html)), all the blogs in the world will spread word.

### How to check it on your own

Knowing the structures how data are saved, you could investigate yourself (if your device is rooted, that is). Andrew Hoog's book [Android Forensics and Mobile Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597496510) is one good source teaching you how to do that:

Apps store their data below the `/data/data`, in a directory with the apps package name as name (for skype, this would be `/data/data/com.skype.merlin_mecha/`). By default, that directory is accessible by the app alone (and, of course, by root) -- which is why it requires root privileges to dig deeper. The basic structure below is as follows:

```
/data/data/com.example.demoapp
├── cache                Directory
│   └── webviewCache     Directory
│       ├── 027e59a0     Cache file
│       └── 057606c4     Cache file
├── databases            Directory
│   └── example.db       SQLite database
├── lib                  Directory
└── shared_prefs         Directory
    └── example.xml      Config file
```

Obviously, there are two major places to check:

1. the `shared_prefs` directory, containing XML files. As those are plain-text, they should be easy to investigate.
2. the `databases` directory. Database files are usually in the SQLite standard, so you can investigate them with either an SQLite command line client, or with a graphical frontend like [SQLiteMan](http://sqliteman.com/).

A thorough information on this topic would go too far here -- but you got the idea, I hope.

### Conclusion

I wouldn't be that much concerned with Samsungs official service (though "bad guys" could sit everywhere -- but one should not go paranoid about it. But of course it is a generally good idea to be careful of which apps one uses. Too late for your current case, might be -- but there's always a tomorrow.

Comment: Nice one, thanks :) Actually, I'm not so worried about Samsung service, but a bit more about the "approved repair center" which is an independent small company.

Btw, Cerberus is installed on my device and I am hesitant to send a "Wipe memory" command on it. I guess Samsung will at some point connect it to the Internet. The command would be executed at this time, so at the end the intermediate company would get a wiped device ; but I am afraid of the reaction of the guy at Samsung handling the phone...

What do you think ?

Comment: Valid point -- at least if you consider your data lost either way. In that case, I'd do it. Not because I'd feel paranoid -- but if I had an easy option and wouldn't use it, and *then* something would go wrong, I'd blame myself for stupidity ;)

Comment: Knowing that the guy at the repair center told me it was likely due to a motherboard fault. If it's true : 1/ the motherboard will be changed, and the old one destroyed (the memory is sealed on it, right?) 2/ it will be repaired, and if the memory remains intact, Cerberus will be able to wipe during it tests process 3/ I get a all new phone and the old one will be securely wiped (I hope) by Samsung for refurbish

Comment: Nope I don't care about getting my data back, I already have backups. I just don't want someone else to access it. So you think I should try to remotely wipe it? I'm just scared of Samsung's reaction. (Concerning warranty, more exactly. Cerberus is an app which needs root access, and my device has been flashed many times. I may be on the edge of a broken warranty. Even though European law says I'm not, I don't know what Samsung intergalactic law says ;))

Comment: So what's the difference (in terms of warranty)? If they look at it, they'll see it was rooted either way. And if you are living inside the EU, EU law should count -- regardless where they repair the device. It's your right to protect your data.

Comment: I meant : seeing such thing happening on the device could cause Samsung to smell a rat (and then check for flash traces).
But that's nitpicking. Remote memory wipe it will be. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: That's a valid point ("wake sleeping dogs") -- but what shall they say? ;) Glad I could help. If you have additional questions, just drop by in the [general chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android).

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) applications will store saved passwords in an encrypted format in their database in their data folder.

As such, your passwords will be safe - they would have to access the database, and then decrypt the stored the encrypted password.

As well as that, they will most likely wipe your device anyway (not always done, depends on the repair).