# Transfer multiple google accounts to a new device

Tags: 7.0-nougat, google-backup

I have several google accounts for different games, work and personal. I have 2 new devices on Android 7.0 Nougat. I would like to know how to transfer then all to the new devices without having to type each and everyone in the devices.

Comment: I don't see another way of doing this than type each individual adress + password!

Comment: So far, that's the way it looks. I used the Samsung smart switch to transfer my data and everything, but the accounts won't transfer. My Samsung email address transferred but not my google.

Comment: It restores what you previously typed.

Comment: Thx esQmo. Appreciate your help. I hope that someone will know a better answer than what we already have. lol

Comment: have a look at this: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29192/how-is-the-gmail-password-stored-in-android-and-where

Comment: Well I copied those files and put them on the other device, changed the permissions but nothing happened.

Comment: I have the same trouble and came across this video on Youtube. You may want to check it out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lZ7dyDd2Nc