# Android gmail password folder

Tags: email, android-versions, google-account

I'd like to ask you how can I get my password of my email that I forgot (it's a Yahoo account).

The account is mine, I changed phone and when I was about to type in gmail-app the password, I couldn't remember it anymore.

The situation is very strange: I can access the account on the older phone, but without password I can't do it on my new phone. I don't remember also secrets questions, and the Yahoo recovery password was insuccesful for me.

What I think I can do is to copy the file in which Android stored my password/hash of my password and copy to my new phone, hoping that this way gmail app would recognise again my email account.

Is it possible? I've already read this [How is the Gmail password stored in Android - and where?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29192/how-is-the-gmail-password-stored-in-android-and-where) but it is not very useful for me: EmailProvider is almost empty of useful information.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a way an Android app works. It stores its password in its data and that data is stored under root folders. In your case you have to communicate with Yahoo community to recover your device and as you said that you are able to access Yahoo account in your phone because you have entered your password once in it and it would be taking it as it is.

Comment: So is there any method I can use to recover my password from data folders? I have a rooted phone also. I tried to contact Yahoo team, but the only things they continue to ask me are secrets questions... Do you know an alternative method to communicate with Yahoo community? I follow their guide to recover account, but without secrets answer or mobile phone (I didn't register one for my email account) I can't do anything. Maybe writing to them and explaining the situation can help? If so, where can I found the email address of Yahoo team?

Comment: You can get some help from https://in.help.yahoo.com/kb/account?guccounter=1 and you cannot just get the data from one phone to another, there are many things which are also stored with password hashes